# HTTP 414 Error while POST to a JAVA WebApp

Tags: java, apache, http, http-post, tomcat7

We're developping a Mobile WebApp that sends data to a JAVA WebApp, the JAVA WebApp is deployed under TOMCAT7, which is configured with Apache using mod_jk.

Every time I use a POST request to send **base64** data I have a **HTTP 414 Error**, googling the error I find that I should set the following for Apache2:

```
LimitRequestLine 819000
LimitRequestFieldSize 819000
```

And the following for Tomcat7:

```
<Connector port="8090" maxHttpHeaderSize="655360" protocol="HTTP/1.1
<Connector port="8010" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" packetsize="655360" maxHttpHeaderSize="655360" />
```

I used a high values to check out if it works, but unfortunately it doesn't.

I used **wc -c** to find out the string byte counts, the result was **34400**

I'll be thankful if someone can help me solving this.

Comment: How long is the URL to which you try to POST?

Comment: @SubOptimal I used wc -c to find out the string byte counts, the result was 34400

Comment: As `HTTP error 414` states the URI is to long, try to find out (network sniffer) what is sent to the server.

Comment: I used wireshark, this is the TCP request

`POST /questionApi/save?questionId=1&&pointOfSaleId=12&&questionOptions=[{%22id%22:%223%22}]&&photo=data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFgAAACCCAYAAADCMA99AAAgAElEQVR4Xsy9B5xcZdk+fJ0yve7FzuckXTl...................`

I removed the rest of the encoded data..
Wireshark said that the size of that is **20440 bytes**

Comment: Then you should try to log this request in the web server to see what he receive and complain about.

Comment: Don't know why, but I think that Wireshark is mistaken about the request size, because I used many other tool to check how many bytes my string has and always find **7989** not 20440.. Sniffing the server side I find that the server get just the first **1497** chars..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71653/discussion-between-elacheche-and-suboptimal).